# php array skip values greater than X

Tags: php, arrays, filter, array-filter

I have an array with values between 1-100. However, in case of an error, is there a way to make one final check just to be sure I skip/ignore values greater than 100 and the output is between 1-100?

Comment: `if` statement and `continue`?

Comment: What do you mean with "in case of an error"? Also please make a little example with an array of like 5 elements of what you *try* to do here.

Comment: Use `array_filter`

Comment: What do you mean by skip values?  Can you make the question clearer?

Comment: As you seem to be making no attempt to improve your question by actually adding some more detail and more importantly some actual code, I suggest we delete this question as it is of no use to others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is where [array_filter()](http://php.net/array_filter) comes in handy.

```
$lower_limit = 1;
$upper_limit = 100;

$array = array_filter(
    $array,
    function ($value) use ($lower_limit, $upper_limit) {
        return ($value >= $lower_limit && $value <= $upper_limit);
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [array_filter](http://php.net/array_filter) is a way to it.

It will iterate through your array and filters it using the supplied function. In the end you'll get an array with only elements between 1 and 100.

```
$arr = array(
    1, 2, 99, 201,
);

$goodArr = array_filter($arr, function($value){
    return ($value >= 1 && $value <= 100);
});
```